# Adding/Removing Methods Causes Exception

Tags: c#, exception

Strange problem. I have a class, and if I add any methods from it (including private methods) it causes an exception in a different class.

The exception is:

```
An exception of type 'System.MemberAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Type initializer was not callable.
```

The line that causes the exception is:

```
compositionService.DefaultCompositionService.SatisfyImportsOnce(this);
```

(`compositionService` is of type `Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel` and `this` is a class that implements the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.TableManager.ITableDataSource` interface.)

This occurs even if I add a method such as:

```
private void DoNothing()
{
}
```

If I remove a class, the exception happens in the same line, but is this exception instead:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll 
but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 
'System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo' to type 
'System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo'.
```

Both the added and removed methods are private.

The code is from https://github.com/vinaykapadia/sarif-sdk in the `Sarif.Viewer.VisualStudio` project, the file I'm adding the `DoNothing()` method to is `CodeAnalysisResultManager.cs`, and the exception is caused in `ErrorList\SarifTableDataSouce.cs` on line 36.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to post _complete_ code so the problem can be identified/replicated. This doesn't mean posting all of your code, only the relavant complete code.

Comment: Yap ! you need to post complete code.and if you are using any specific library ,framework or design pattern . 
having the following in the error :
'' 'System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo' to type 
'System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo'.  " , gives me the feeling that it's a naming convention conflict kind of thing .

Comment: Sure, I'll add a few details tomorrow.

Comment: I'm not sure what code would be relevant or not, but the code is open source. I'll add info in the question text.

Comment: https://github.com/vinaykapadia/sarif-sdk is 404 now. Was it a fork of https://github.com/microsoft/sarif-sdk ?